# Trouble showing spans of two bases are equivalent

Tags: linear-algebra

I was given the following problem:

Let V be a vector space over field F. Show that x,y $\in$ V form a basis iff x+y, x-y form a basis.

But I seem to be stuck when showing the span of one basis equals that of the other. For example, in the reverse direction I said:

Assume R = $\{$x+y, x-y$\}$ is a basis. So V = Span$\{$R$\}$ = $\{$$\alpha_{1}$(x + y) + $\alpha_{2}$(x - y) | $\alpha_{1}$, $\alpha_{2}$ $\in$ F$\}$ = $\{$($\alpha_{1}$ + $\alpha_{2}$)x + ($\alpha_{1}$ - $\alpha_{2}$)y$\}$ = Span$\{$x, y$\}$. (then I show linear independence to show it's a basis)

My thinking is that, since F is a field and $\alpha_{1}$ and $\alpha_{2}$ are arbitrary, $\alpha_{1}$ + $\alpha_{2}$ and $\alpha_{1}$ - $\alpha_{2}$ themselves represent arbitrary elements of the field (since a field will be closed under addition and subtraction, so every element must be either a sum or difference of two other elements). Is this incorrect? Is there something more I am supposed to show here to prove equivalence of the two spans? Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's fine for me. The key step for me is to show $\{\alpha_1(x+y)+\alpha_2(x-y):\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in F\}=\{\alpha_1x+\alpha_2y:\alpha_1,\alpha_2\in F\}$. I think you have to explain that more carefully.

Comment: Do you mean I should show the intermediate step where I reorganize, or that I should actually write out the reasoning instead of simply going from A to B? And thank you for your help.

Comment: You should write down the reasoning.